# Stopwatch function that saves time after reboot/closing

Tags: windows, time-management

I need to count the number of hours I am working on a certain project. Is there Windows 8 app or a small software that acts as a stopwatch but that can also save the elapsed time after I reboot and potentially save different elapsed times for different projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I have used [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/), it tracks individual files, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! But could you please [edit] your answer and add a few more details (see our [answer quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) for details)? With a link to where one can find the software, plus some details on the pricing and what makes it recommendable, your answer would be much more useful :) Thanks in advance for your update!

Answer (score 0):

I use something called timeEdition. The [old version](https://www.timeedition.com/old/en/downloads/index.html) works with Linux, Mac and Windows. The [new version](http://www.timeedition.com/en/) currently works with Android, IOS and they are in the process of updating it for Mac.